# How do I resize an entire one page, multi-image, multi-layered document in Indesign CS6

Tags: adobe-indesign

I'd like to take a 22x77" file and make it 15x52".  How is that done without having to resize every image.  This file contains hundreds of images.

Comment: Those are different ratios, so you probably can’t.

Comment: @Janus Bahs Jacquet I guess you could with liquid layout but that would take longer to set up than scaling things manually would take

Comment: @JulianSteinmann Does CS6 even have liquid layout? I can’t remember anymore, just kind of assumed that was a CC thing.

Comment: Oh haven't seen that. Yes I think your right it's pretty new probably since CC.

Comment: I've honestly *never* used it, but Liquid Layout exists in CS6. An answer regarding that may well indeed be helpful. I can't tag ya both `:)` @JanusBahsJacquet

Comment: @JulianSteinmann See comment above `:)`

Answer (score 1):

##### Liquid layout

There is a "Liquid layout panel" (under "Windows/Interactive") that offers a lot of settings how elements should scale with the page. The option "Object based" with "Width" and "Height" checked for example will stretch all content. Probably best to watch a video tutorial on this if you want to learn more about all other options of this.

[image]

##### Adjust layout

The "Adjust layout" button in the page setup will do about the same but with less extra settings. Note that both of those will need some corrections afterward like the margins between the images. Adjust layout will also work with multiple pages which can be very useful for big books.

[image]

##### Manually

But really in most cases I personally find it fastest to do it manually. (Though I do not do a lot of work that needs to be exported in different sizes, what would make the above tools really helpful).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty, but its about the only way....

- Select All
- `Object > Group`
- Change the document size
- Grab the **Free Transform Tool**
- Hold down the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key and drag a corner handle on the group's bounding box.

**The document sizes are *not proportional* so it's not going to be a "perfect fit" when scaling.**

Drag to scale down to get as close as you can while still holding the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key.  Just get as close as you can. Typically getting the *width* to fit is the easiest moving forward. When you are close with that let go of the mouse.

Now choose `Object > Ungroup` and *manually* reposition elements to fit the new proportions.

You will *absolutely* want to check type sizes after scaling. It's not unheard of for scaling to result in 1 to 3pt type which is nearly impossible to hold.